# Two columns with CSS and html ain't working

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to put a news column and a login column side by side, but what happens is that one goes below the other.

I already have the header and footer of the page worked out, I just am having some problems with the main part. Here is my code.

CSS Code:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#container {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#headline {
    width: 575px;
    height: 220px;
    background-image: url('/images/background_news.png');
}

#headlinetext {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 280px
}

#userlogin {
    background-image: url('/images/area_login.png');
    width: 273px;
    height: 206px;
}

#logintext {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 273px
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="headline">
    <div id="headlinetext">
    <font size="4">Text</font>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="userlogin"> 
    <div id="logintext">
    <form method="post" action="validateuser.php">
    <label>Usu·rio: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" size="20" /><br>
    <label>Senha: </label><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" size="20" /><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a JsFiddle to help visualize my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cNqqJ/

The container tag is repeated because I have 3 separate CSS files, not sure if that is a good excuse.

Comment: Is that all of the html code? If yes, you're missing a closing </div> tag for the container. Most of the time, if an item is showing below another then it means that the containing div is not wide enough to display them side-by-side. Use a tool like firefox dev toolbar to take a look and see what's causing the issue.

Comment: Did you tried using `display: inline;` for `#headline` and `#userlogin`?

Comment: a jsfiddle is usually very helpful to show your point. Consider adding that.

Comment: Theres no div missing, as long as i can see in the editor. I created a jsfiddle to help it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/cNqqJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish: [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EJK5L/4/)

You can add `float: left;` to `#userlogin` and `#headline` divs:

```
#userlogin 
{
    background-image: url('/images/area_login.png');
    width: 273px;
    height: 206px;
    float: left; /* Added */
}

#userlogin 
{
    background-image: url('/images/area_login.png');
    width: 273px;
    height: 206px;
    float: left; /* Added */
}
```

If you are having issues with the "body" not being used, as you mentioned, you might want to wrap this "login" area inside a wrapper, something like this:

```
<div id='logincontainer'>
    <div id='headline'>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#logincontainer { height: 220px; }
```

Comment: I added float:left already but the thing is that the bottom part comes up behind then, like the body wasn't filling a space.

Comment: @Gilson - could you make a jsFiddle or a screenshot possibly displaying what it looks like or what you are trying to accomplish. It's a bit difficult trying to visualize.

Comment: I added the line display:inline-block; on #headline and #userlogin it kind of helped, but they are not aligned properly :/

Comment: I think I got what you are trying to accomplish - are you talking about how those two areas ignore the "body" area in the background?

Comment: I want a layout with the header, thats the logo and the menus and right below on the left i want the news block and on the right the login block and bellow those two the footer with copyright and all that stuff. If i use float: left; on both of then they stay side by side the way i want, but the footer comes up and screw it up

Comment: I made a change - try wrapping the headline and userlogin divs with the #logincontainer that I had mentioned. That should give you the space and keep the footer pushed down. You should be able to adjust the height by changing the logincontainer height. (Updated the demo with the logincontainer as well)

Comment: Dude, it worked like a charm! hahaha thank you, appreciate all the effort! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to float the #headerline and #userlogin divs, otherwise what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Try adding a

```
float: left;
```

to the #headline div

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.
First off the #container tag never terminates, close it.

Second off, you need to float your two columns:

```
#headline {
    width: 575px;
    height: 220px;
    background-image: url('/images/background_news.png');
    float: left; 
}

#userlogin {
    background-image: url('/images/area_login.png');
    width: 273px;
    height: 206px;
    float: left; 
}
```

Comment: I added float:left already but the thing is that the bottom part comes up behind then, like the body wasn't filling a space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add float left to the sections that you want side by side. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/danielcgold/aD2yH/

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `float:left;` to your two `div`s

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JRumr/

You could also use `display:inline-block;`

Second example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JRumr/1/